# Do sample sizes of data change once the data is weighted? How do you report statistical results with weighted data?

Tags: statistics

I'm using the CDC's BRFSS data which is population level data by state. The CDC states in using the data you should weight the data to be more representative of the population. Thus in SPSS click DATA > WEIGHT CASES > WEIGHT CASES BY....[insert variable here]. I weight the data by the recommended variable created by the CDC already in the BRFSS data set, but then run a MANOVA and I'm getting a hugely inflated N for my analysis. Is this correct? My original sample size is approximately 6000, then after weighting jumps up to 1144000.

Answer (score 0):

Weighting cases allows to assign some level of "importance" or "weight" to the cases in a dataset. To do this, the procedure "multiplies" each row for the corresponding value of the weighting varable. So the final $N$ in your MANOVA is the sum of the values of the weighting variable. However, this does not mean that the sample size is changed.